# SQL Server don't run in sqlcmd but run in ssms

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, sqlcmd

I have a problem with a script running under sqlcmd vs SSMS.

The first time that I had the problem, I cut the large file (a lot of inserts) into small pieces, cutting it in blocks of 2000 inserts.

In sqlcmd log I get this error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: syntax error at line 75 near command '1' in finle 'D:\vbmania\migrador\migrador-forum-1.sql'.

Ok, a syntax error...but when I check the file, well... I don't have any kind of syntax problem.

If I take the same file and run in SSMS, it works fine:

[Run in SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSDbV.png)

To execute the files in batch mode:

```
sqlcmd -b -S MICRO9\SQLEXPRESS -V 17 -i D:\xxx\migrador\migrador-forum-130.sql -o D:\xxx\migrador\migrador-forum-130.log
sqlcmd -b -S MICRO9\SQLEXPRESS -V 17 -i D:\xxx\migrador\migrador-forum-131.sql -o D:\xxx\migrador\migrador-forum-131.log
```

And a sample of the insert structure:

```sql
insert into Forum (id, parente, titulo, texto, mundoid, destaque, destaqueglobal, bloqueado, bloqueadorid, bloqueadoem, respostas, vistos, pontos, anexo, interado, ip, usuarioid, criado) 
values ('19656', '19371', 'TÓPICO', 'texthere', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '18/08/2009 10:03:45', '0', '1', '0', NULL, '09/04/2004 15:34:23', '200.163.161.xxx', '10', '09/04/2004 15:34:23')

insert into Forum (id, parente, titulo, texto, mundoid, destaque, destaqueglobal, bloqueado, bloqueadorid, bloqueadoem, respostas, vistos, pontos, anexo, interado, ip, usuarioid, criado) 
values ('19659', NULL, 'CALCULADORA', 'othertext', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '18/08/2009 10:03:45', '1', '992', '0', NULL, '10/04/2004 01:42:51', '200.175.43.xxx', '10', '09/04/2004 15:40:24')
```

I did a sanitize function to replace invalid characters (SQL injection) to html entities and ensure that SQL is valid (and again, via SSMS it works fine).

I need to run more than 100 files via batch, any suggestion / idea for understand if is a memory leak in sqlcmd or something like that (the files has 1.5MB around)

Comment: When posting on [so], content needs to be in English. This includes error messages.

Comment: You may have some $ chbaracters in your file being interpreted by sqlcmd.

Comment: @Larnu fixed error messages

Comment: @DaveCluderay ...hmmm, probably I have this character , but any flag can be passed to sqlcmd to ignore it ?

Comment: Replacing characters is not a way to prevent sql injection. The way to prevent sql injection is to parameterize your queries.

Answer (score 2):

To disable variable substitution in sqlcmd, use -x, eg

```
sqlcmd -x -b -S MICRO9\SQLEXPRESS -V 17 -i D:\xxx\migrador\migrador-forum-130.sql -o D:\xxx\migrador\migrador-forum-130.log
```

and

```
PS C:\temp> echo 'select ''$(path)'' a' > foo.sql
PS C:\temp> sqlcmd -x -i ".\foo.sql"
```

outputs

```
a
------
$(path)
```